# Как взаимодействовать с элементом ::after с помощью XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xmlparser

Недавно начал изучать xpath, нужно было извлечь данные о времени работы аптеки. Время работы находиться в элементе after, путь к которому я написать не смог. Также заметил что элемент отображается в DevTools, а в исходном коде страницы на этом же месте его нет из-за чего так происходит? Сайт в котором велась работа https://fialkaspb.ru/pharmacy/, путь к родительскому элементу //div[@class="item__address item__address--ninetoten"]

Answer (score 0):

:after это псевдоэлемент, который задается через стили. Физически after не присутствует в html коде, на сайте https://fialkaspb.ru/pharmacy/ значение псевдоэлемента задается через js

[Почитать про after](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Выглядит так, что через xpath не получить нужные вам значения

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете получить значение элемента с помощью JS:

```
const pharmacies = document.querySelectorAll('.item__address');

pharmacies.forEach(pharmacy => {
  const time = window.getComputedStyle(pharmacy,':after').getPropertyValue('content');
  console.log(time)
});
```